# How to load text file in typedef struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scanf

I am having a problem to save all elements in when ı print it prints first line, or it prints with errors and bugs, ı want to start from second line.
Text in file:

```
5 5 7
H 1 1 MILK White liquid produced by the mammals
H 2 1 IN Used to indicate inclusion within space, a place, or limits
H 3 3 BUS A road vehicle designed to carry many passengers
H 5 3 DAN The name of a famous author whose surname is Brown
V 1 1 MIND A set of cognitive faculties, e.g. consciousness, perception, etc.
V 3 3 BAD Opposite of good
V 2 5 ISBN International Standard Book Number
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
 char *word; //word and corresponding hint
 char *clue;
 int x; //Starting x and y positions
 int y;
 char direction; //H for horizontal, V for vertical
 int f; //solved or not
} Word_t;

int main()
{
int nrWords=7;
FILE * fpointer = fopen("puzzle2010.txt","r");
loadTextFile(fpointer,nrWords);
return 0;
}

Word_t* loadTextFile( FILE* fpointer, int nrWords ){
    Word_t* tfile;
    int deta,dete,data;
    int i=0;
    char skip[100];
    tfile = (Word_t*) malloc(sizeof(Word_t)*nrWords);
    for(i=0;i<nrWords;i++){
        if(i==0){
            fscanf(fpointer,"%d %d %d ",&data,&dete,&deta);
            printf("%d %d %d \n",data,dete,deta);
        }
        else{
        fscanf(fpointer,"%c %d %d %s %s ",&tfile[i].direction,&tfile[i].x,&tfile[i].y,tfile[i].word,&tfile[i].clue);
        printf("%c %d %d %s %s ",tfile[i].direction,tfile[i].x,tfile[i].y,tfile[i].word,tfile[i].clue);
        }
    }
    fclose(fpointer);


}
```

Comment: Your `clue` and `word` don't have any storage allocated to them. Consider either making these fixed size arrays, or allocating memory for them.

Comment: You're skipping the first element of the `tfile` array. Instead of using `if (i == 0)` inside the loop to read the first line, do that *before* the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't the function end with `return tfile;`?

Comment: How can ı allocate inside the function or do ı have to allocate them inside the typedef

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for the answer Hasturkun  ı allocate word and clue in the for loop and ı use fgets  for put string in tfile[i].clue`tfile[i].word=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        tfile[i].clue=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100); fscanf(fpointer,"%c %d %d %s",&tfile[i].direction,&tfile[i].x,&tfile[i].y,tfile[i].word);
        fgets(tfile[i].clue,100,fpointer);
        printf("%c %d %d %s %s ",tfile[i].direction,tfile[i].x,tfile[i].y,tfile[i].word,tfile[i].clue);`

Comment: OT: regarding: `tfile = (Word_t*) malloc(sizeof(Word_t)*nrWords);`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror()` to have both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  I.E. `perror( "Your Error Message" );`

Comment: the posted code is missing a prototype (before `main()` for the function: `loadTextFile()` which results in the compiler assuming that any parameters (and the return type) are all `int`

Comment: regarding the function: `Word_t* loadTextFile( FILE* fpointer, int nrWords )` that function is missing a `return` statement that returns an instance of a `Word_t` pointer

Comment: the function: `loadTextFile()`  claims that is returns a `Word_t*`  but the call in `main()` fails to check for that returned type.

Comment: OT: regarding; `FILE * fpointer = fopen("puzzle2010.txt","r");`  When calling `fopen()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) the call `perror( "fopen failed" );`  which will output to `stderr`, both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int nrWords=7;`  this puts some serious constraints on the contents of the input file.  And will make the overall code easily broken.  Suggest starting: `t_file = NULL;` then calling `realloc()` each time another set of data from the input file is to be read.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care)  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding statements like: `fscanf(fpointer,"%d %d %d ",&data,&dete,&deta);`  The function: `fscanf()` returns the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifications (or EOF)   The code should always check that returned value to assure the desired operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code results in a memory leak because the allocated memory (pointed to by `t_file`) is never returned to the heap, via a call to `free()`;

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(fpointer,"%c %d %d %s %s ",&tfile[i].direction,&tfile[i].x,&tfile[i].y,tfile[i].word,&tfile[i].clue);`  This will fail to read in more than the first word of the 'clue' because the input format conversion specifier: `%s` stops when it encounters any `white space`.  Suggest using a char set like: `%[^\n]` which will input everything until a newline is encountered.  Note: this will leave the newline in `stdin` so this statement; `fscanf(fpointer,"%c %d %d %s %s ",....);` should have a leading space before the `%c` so as to consume the leading white space.